# Automatically delete row from database after 6 months

Tags: java, database, postgresql, spring-boot

I want my program to delete old stories from my database. When a story gets 6 months old, it should get deleted automatically.

```
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    private long id;
    private String title;
    
    @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String content;
    private Date posted;
```

I have no idea how to even start programming it. I've read that it's slow and that I need some kind of event, but I don't know how to do it. I'd be really happy if you could help me with this.

Comment: Partitioning is the keyword if you want to delete large amounts of data. This doesn't work automatically though.

Comment: See also sister site, DBA.StackExchange.com, [*Automatic aging-out (deletion) of old records in Postgres*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/106827/19079).

Answer (score 1):

You could use `@Scheduled` to run a method on a specific instant and check if there is data older than 6 month.

For example

```
@Component
public class Janior {

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 0 * * ?") // this will run daily
    public void deleteOldStories() {
       // delete all entries older than 6 month
    }
}
```

Make sure that you add `@EnableScheduling` to your SpringBootApplication class.

Read more about scheduling: https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/